# Running .bat file in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a .bat file in my Google Colab notebook, howere I cannot seem to make it happen. Whenever I navigate to the folder the code says the directory or file does not exist.

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("batch.bat", cwd=r"/content/drive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion/merge-models-main/")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Colab is an Ubuntu Linux environment so it will struggle if the file to be run contains Windows like commands. If the file contains Linux shell commands then the following code illustrates how to execute these.

This cell makes a `batch.bat` file (purists would argue that it should be `batch.sh`).

```
# This is a Unix shell script
with open('batch.bat', 'w') as f:
    f.write('var=$(date)\r\n')
    f.write('echo "$var" > output.txt\r\n')
```

The file is placed into `/content/` by default. If you want to use a file from your own Google Drive, you have to mount this yourself.

To execute the commands in the file do this. Note how `Popen` takes a list with the location of the file to execute as the second parameter.

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(["/bin/sh", "/content/batch.bat"])
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Look for the file `output.txt` and observe the timestamp in it. This should give an indication whether it is working.